# Is there a way to detect if a website is mobile friendly from the unix command line?

Tags: php, mobile, detect

I'm trying to detect if a website is mobile friendly in a scripted way.

Preferably using php loading and parsing the html of the website. Is there any known way of doing this?

Right now the only thing i can think of is to detect the viewport meta tag.

Comment: You'd have to define "mobile friendly". That encompasses many things from CSS, to Javascript fiddling, to, as you mentioned, the viewpoint settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could search for width=device-width in a meta tag. There is no HTML tag or attribute which really defines mobile friendly.

Comment: And also get the CSS and search by `@media `

Answer (score 1):

Found from this link: [Script to Mobile-Friendly test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616894/script-to-mobile-friendly-test][1])

Call google API, with JSON encoding to check for mobile friendliness.

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?url=[http site to check]